# Rerun JavaFX application

Tags: javafx, intellij-plugin

I'm developing a plugin for IntelliJ. It is a menu that has only one option, and clicking it starts a JavaFX application. The application starts normally, but when I close the application and start again I get the following error:

java.lang.IllegalStateException: Application launch must not be called more than once

It's a simple application, the code is as follows:

This is the code in the menu.

```
try {
    Application.launch(MyApplication.class);
} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

This is the JavaFX Application.

```
public class MyApplication extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {

        try {
            FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource("/fxml/main-window.fxml"));
            loader.setController(new MainController());

            AnchorPane root = loader.load();
            Scene scene = new Scene(root, 1000, 600);

            primaryStage.setScene(scene);
            primaryStage.setMaximized(false);
            primaryStage.setResizable(false);

            primaryStage.show();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

How can I rerun the application? I tried to follow some answers here on the site, but I did not understand them very well, nor could I execute them correctly.

Comment: The application is probably still running, even if no UI is visible. How do you quit the application? The JavaFX thread should also be visible somewhere, indicating that it is still running.

Comment: i tried to use the stop() method of the Application and Platform.exit(), and none worked.